# Images appearing in front of menu

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I have a small bug where the images in one section appears in front of my menu. I tried to play around the z-index value but nothing worked for me. [Here is what it looks like](https://gyazo.com/8a6f8489d1aa000b4d49b4341908a3f0)

I would like the images to be under the menu as-per, but it does not seem to function properly and I cannot detect the problem, can someone help me out with this?

HTML:

```
<section id="portfolio">
 <div class="container">
<h1>MY WORK</h1>
<h2>Below you will find my favorite projects & school assignments</h2>
<!--CPU-->
<div class="project">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="./img/cpu.png">
    <div class="hovertext">Test Text 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--JAVA-->
<div class="project">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="./img/JSON.png">
    <div class="hovertext">Test Text 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--PHOTOSHOP-->
<div class="project">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="./img/photoshop.png">
    <div class="hovertext">Test Text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio {
   background-color: : white;
   padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#portfolio h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

#portfolio h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.project {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.img-box {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.project img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.img-box img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.img-box .hovertext {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.img-box:hover .hovertext {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Did you try giving higher z-index to menu bar?

Comment: Set z-index to have the menu-bar on the top.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Where is your menu code?

Comment: Please add z-index to have the top menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test but maybe will work.

```
<div class="container" style="z-index: -999999">
```